# Calling async methods (Vert.x, Java) from necessarily synchronous ones

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, vert.x, shiro

We have a set of Java applications that were originally written using normal synchronous methods but have largely been converted to asynchronous Vert.x (the regular API, not Rx) wherever it makes sense. We're having some trouble at the boundaries between sync and async code, especially when we have a method that must be synchronous (reasoning explained below) and we want to invoke an async method from it.

There are many similar questions asked previously on Stack Overflow, but practically all of them are in a C# context and the answers do not appear to apply.

Among other things we are using Geotools and Apache Shiro. Both provide customization through extension using APIs they have defined that are strictly synchronous. As a specific example, our custom authorization realm for Shiro needs to access our user data store, for which we have created an async DAO API. The Shiro method we have to write is called `doGetAuthorizationInfo;` it is expected to return an `AuthorizationInfo`. But there does not appear to be a reliable way to access the authorization data from the other side of the async DAO API.

In the specific case that the thread was not created by Vert.x, using a `CompletableFuture` is a workable solution: the synchronous `doGetAuthorizationInfo` would push the async work over to a Vert.x thread and then block the current thread in `CompletableFuture.get()` until the result becomes available.

Unfortunately the Shiro (or Geotools, or whatever) method may be invoked on a Vert.x thread. In that case it is extremely bad to block the current thread: if it's the event loop thread then we're breaking the Golden Rule, while if it's a worker thread (say, via `Vertx.executeBlocking`) then blocking it will prevent the worker from picking up anything more from its queue - meaning the blocking will be permanent.

Is there a "standard" solution to this problem? It seems to me that it will crop up anytime Vert.x is being used under an extensible synchronous library. Is this just a situation that people avoid?

### EDIT

... with a bit more detail. Here is a snippet from org.apache.shiro.realm.AuthorizingRealm:

```
/**
 * Retrieves the AuthorizationInfo for the given principals from the underlying data store.  When returning
 * an instance from this method, you might want to consider using an instance of
 * {@link org.apache.shiro.authz.SimpleAuthorizationInfo SimpleAuthorizationInfo}, as it is suitable in most cases.
 *
 * @param principals the primary identifying principals of the AuthorizationInfo that should be retrieved.
 * @return the AuthorizationInfo associated with this principals.
 * @see org.apache.shiro.authz.SimpleAuthorizationInfo
 */
protected abstract AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals);
```

Our data access layer has methods like this:

```
void loadUserAccount(String id, Handler<AsyncResult<UserAccount>> handler);
```

How can we invoke the latter from the former? If we knew `doGetAuthorizationInfo` was being invoked in a non-Vert.x thread, then we could do something like this:

```
@Override
protected AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals) {
    CompletableFuture<UserAccount> completable = new CompletableFuture<>();
    vertx.<UserAccount>executeBlocking(vertxFuture -> {
        loadUserAccount((String) principals.getPrimaryPrincipal(), vertxFuture);
    }, res -> {
        if (res.failed()) {
            completable.completeExceptionally(res.cause());
        } else {
            completable.complete(res.result());
        }
    });

    // Block until the Vert.x worker thread provides its result.
    UserAccount ua = completable.get();

    // Build up authorization info from the user account
    return new SimpleAuthorizationInfo(/* etc...*/);
}
```

But if `doGetAuthorizationInfo` is called in a Vert.x thread then things are completely different. The trick above will block an event loop thread, so that's a no-go. Or if it's a worker thread then the `executeBlocking` call will put the `loadUserAccount` task onto the queue for that same worker (I believe), so the subsequent `completable.get()` will block permanently.

Comment: Can you update your question with small snippets of interfaces involved? It will be easier to shape an answer. `CompletionStage` has methods to execute callbacks on specific executors so this might a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet you know the answer already, but are wishing it wasn't so -- If a call to GeoTools or Shiro will need to block waiting for a response from something, then you shouldn't be making that call on a Vert.x thread.

You should create an `ExecutorService` with a thread pool that you should use to execute those calls, arranging for each submitted task to send a Vert.x message when it's done.

You may have some flexibility in the size of the chunks you move into the thread pool.  Instead of tightly wrapping those calls, you can move something larger higher up the call stack.  You will probably make this decision based on how much code you will have to change.  Since making a method asynchronous usually implies changing *all* the synchronous methods in its call stack anyway (that's the unfortunate fundamental problem with this kind of async model), you will probably want to do it high on the stack.

You will probably end up with an adapter layer that provides Vert.x APIs for a variety of synchronous services.

Comment: +1 I cannot answer anything on the Vert.x side, but you can create associate a thread with a Shiro subject like this: https://shiro.apache.org/subject.html#thread-association, then plug that into you your ExecutorService

Comment: @Matt Timmermans Yes, you hit the nail on the head. Based on the docs I had the impression that blocking a worker thread was okay, so when we initially coded the call to the GeoTools map render method, for example, I wrapped it in an executeBlocking call like a good boy. All was fine, until we tried to implement an ExternalGraphicFactory for rendering custom markers on the map. Since the source for these markers is reached via our async API, we hit the problem immediately. Confusingly, it _sometimes_ worked. Ah well!

Comment: @BrianDemers  Shiro's use of ThreadLocals exposed a slightly different problem actually, which is that Vert.x provides no control over how its threads are created. We had already adapted to that reality by (essentially) determining the current thread's Subject in web request handlers, resolving all the authorization data immediately, and carrying that down into our async code as method parameter payload. Messy but workable, and fairly straightforward since we're using GWT with a Shiro filter. Therefore we didn't need the association technique you mentioned, but now we probably will. Thanks.